# Excepciones c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que realizar unas excepciones para posibles errores, quisiera que si en el menú digitan una letra apareciera un error de escritura, y en las notas no digitar una nota menor que 0.0 y tampoco mayor que 5.0.
Las excepciones deben estar en una clase hija.

Intenté hacerlo pero la verdad no pude. 
 lo hice con archivos de cabecera.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "classpersona.h"
#include "estudiante.h"
#include "profesor.h"
#include "exception.h"

using namespace std;

void salir();
int opc;
int main(){
    persona p(" "," ");
    estudiante e(" "," "," ",0,0,0,0,0);
    profesor pro(" "," "," "," "," ");
do{  
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Bienvenido"<<endl;
    cout<<"Digite una opcion"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Datos personales "<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Datos del estudiante "<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Datos del profesor "<<endl;
    cout<<"4.mostrar "<<endl;
    cout<<"5.salir"<<endl;
    cin>>opc;


     switch(opc){
            case 1: p.ingresar();
            break;
            case 2: e.ingresar();
            break;
            case 3: pro.ingresar();
            break;
            case 4: e.mostrar(), p.mostrar(),pro.mostrar();
            break;
            case 5: salir();
            break;
            }  


     }while(opc!=5);

system("pause");
return(0);   
}           



void salir(){
     cout<<"Buen dia"<<endl;
     }

//1 archivo de cabecera.


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class persona{
      public:
//atributos
string direccion;
string telefono;

//metodos
virtual void ingresar();
void mostrar();

//constructor      
   persona(string,string);   

};

persona::persona(string _direccion, string _telefono){

          direccion=_direccion;
          telefono=_telefono;
};

void persona::ingresar(){
     cout<<"Ingrese su direccion:  "<<endl;
     cin>>direccion;
     cout<<"Ingrese su Telefono:  "<<endl;
     cin>>telefono;
     system("pause");

     }
void persona::mostrar(){
     cout<<" "<<endl;
     cout<<"La direccion del estudiante es:  "<<direccion<<endl;
     cout<<"El Telefono del estudiante es:   "<<telefono<<endl;

}     


//2 archivo de cabecera.


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class estudiante: public persona{
      public:
//atributos
string materia;
float n1;
float n2;
float n3;
float n4;
float promedio;
//metodos
void ingresar();
void mostrar();
void promedio1();
//constructor 
estudiante(string,string,string,float,float,float,float,float);

};    

estudiante::estudiante(string _direccion, string _telefono,string _materia,float _n1,float _n2,float _n3,float _n4,float _promedio): persona(_direccion,_telefono){
                              materia=_materia;
                              n1=_n1;    
                              n2=_n2;  
                              n3=_n3;  
                              n4=_n4;
                              promedio=_promedio;                                  
};       

void estudiante:: ingresar(){
     cout<<"Ingrese la materia:  "<<endl;
     cin>>materia;
    try{
    cout<<"Ingrese la nota 1 "<<endl;
     cin>>n1;
     cout<<"Ingrese la nota 2 "<<endl;
     cin>>n2;
     cout<<"Ingrese la nota 3 "<<endl;
     cin>>n3;
     cout<<"Ingrese la nota 4 "<<endl;
     cin>>n4;
    if(n1||n2||n3||n4>5.0){
          throw n1,n2,n3,n4;
          ;
     }else{
          }
    catch(exception& e){}
         }
}





void estudiante::promedio1(){

promedio=(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;

}     
void estudiante::mostrar(){
     cout<<" "<<endl;
     estudiante::promedio1();
 cout<<"El promedio del estudiante es: "<<promedio<<endl;    
 cout<<"La materia que cursa es: "<<materia<<endl;

          }

//3 archivo de cabecera.

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class profesor:public persona{
  public:
  //Atributos
  string nombre;
  string direccion1;
  string telefono1;
  //Metodos
  void ingresar();
  void mostrar();
  //constructor
   profesor(string,string,string,string,string);    
};

profesor::profesor(string _direccion, string _telefono,string _nombre,string _direccion1,string _telefono1): persona(_direccion,_telefono){

                 nombre=_nombre;
                 direccion1=_direccion1;
                 telefono1=_telefono1;

};
void profesor::ingresar(){
     cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del profesor"<<endl;
     cin>>nombre;
     cout<<"Ingrese la direccion del profesor:  "<<endl;
     cin>>direccion1;
     cout<<"Ingrese el Telefono del profesor:  "<<endl;
     cin>>telefono1;

     }
void profesor::mostrar(){
     cout<<" "<<endl;
     cout<<"El nombre del profesor es:  "<<nombre<<endl;
     cout<<"La direccion del profesor es:  "<<direccion1<<endl;
     cout<<"El Telefono del profesor es:   "<<telefono1<<endl;
     system("pause");
}     

// archivo de cabecera de la exepcion

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class exception: public persona{
      public:
             catch(exception* e){
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
 }             

};
```

Comment: Yo no veo rastro de las excepciones por ningún lado... ¿qué has intentado exactamente?

Comment: si que pena me falto enviar la parte de la exepcion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tengo que realizar unas excepciones para posibles errores, quisiera que si en el menú digitan una letra apareciera un error de escritura, y en las notas no digitar una nota menor que 0.0 y tampoco mayor que 5.0. Las excepciones deben estar en una clase hija.

Nada de esto tiene sentido en C++.

---

#### Las excepciones son, para casos excepcionales.

Como su nombre indica, las excepciones deben usarse cuando sucede algo excepcional durante la ejecución del código. Son un mecanismo de control de errores no un mecanismo de control del flujo del programa.

Que el usuario introduzca un dato inesperado, o datos en un rango inadecuado no es algo excepcional (los usuarios son idiotas<sup>1</sup>) si no algo que forma parte del flujo normal del programa.

#### ¡Sucedió algo terrible! Intentaré arreglarlo… o delegaré.

Lo habitual y recomendado respecto al uso de excepciones es detectar el error en tiempo de ejecución y hacer lo posible por restablecer el funcionamiento normal de la aplicación; si esto último no es posible: la excepción deberá desplazarse por la pila de llamadas hasta que alguien pueda hacerse cargo o finalizar la aplicación si en ningún contexto se sabe resolver el problema.

Por este motivo no tiene sentido que las excepciones pertenezcan a una jerarquía de clases restrictiva, a no ser que después sean re-lanzadas como una excepción más genérica.

#### Propuesta.

Para comprobar *si si en el menú digitan una letra* no deberías capturar la entrada de usuario en un entero, captura una cadena que después transformarás a número:

```
std::string opc;
std::cin >> opc;

try
{
    switch (std::stoi(opc))
    {
        // Hacer cosas...
    }
}
catch (const std::invalid_argument &no_es_numero)
{
    std::cout << "Error de escritura: '" << opc << "' no es una opcion valida\n";
}
```

La función [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) transforma una cadena en un número, en caso de no poder hacer ninguna conversión lanza una excepción de tipo [`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) que podrás capturar y actuar en consecuencia.

Respecto a las notas:

```
void estudiante:: ingresar(){
    std::cout << "Ingrese la materia:  \n";
    std::cin >> materia;
    try{
        float notas[4]{};

        for (int nota = 0; nota != 4; ++nota) {
            std::cout << "Ingrese la nota " << (nota + 1) << '\n';
            std::cin >> notas[nota];
            if (notas[nota] < .0f || notas[nota] > 5.f) {
                throw std::out_of_range{std::to_string(notas[nota]}
            }
        }

        n1 = notas[0];
        n2 = notas[1];
        n3 = notas[2];
        n4 = notas[3];
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range &nota_no_valida) {
        std::cout << "Una nota esta fuera de rango: " << nota_no_valida.what();
    }
}
```

Tienes muchas cosas mal en tu código. Los `catch` deben emparejarse con un `try`, no deben estar *dentro* de ellos. Respecto a tu `throw`, no puedes lanzar varios objetos a la vez, la instrucción `throw n1,n2,n3,n4` lanzará el último valor ignorando el resto; pero tiene poco sentido lanzar un número como excepción, por ello lo he substituido por la excepción [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range), que tiene sentido en este contexto.

Si te fijas, en caso de excepción los valores `n1`, `n2`, `n3` y `n4` no son modificados, esto es una buena práctica asociada al uso de excepciones: si sucede un error durante la ejecución del código de la clase `estudiante` se aconseja que la instancia se quede en un estado utilizable (que se recupere adecuadamente del error).

---

1. La programación es una carrera entre los ingenieros de software esforzándose por crear los mejores y mayores programas a prueba de idiotas, y el Universo intentando producir mejores y mayores idiotas. Por ahora, el universo va ganando — [Rick Cook](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rick_Cook) —

Comment: Muchas gracias, hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo a programar y pues en la enseñanza se comenten muchos errores, lo importante es aprender de ello.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de manejo de excepciones en C++ te puede servir:

```
#include "iostream"
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;



enum error {datos_no_validos};


void validar(double radio, double diametro) throw(error){
  if(radio <= 0.0 && diametro <= 0.0){
    throw datos_no_validos;
  }
}

class Circulo{
private:
    double radio;
    double diametro;
public:
    static const double PI=3.1459;
    Circulo(){cout<<"objeto circulo creado"<<endl;}
    virtual ~Circulo(){cout<<"objeto circulo destruido"<<endl;}
    void setRadio(double r){this->radio=r;}
    double getRadio(){return this->radio;}
    void setDiametro(double d){this->diametro=d;}
    double getDiametro(){return this->diametro;}
    double calc_diametro(){return this->diametro*PI;}
    double calc_area(){return PI*(this->radio*this->radio);}
};


int main(){
    Circulo circulo=Circulo();
    double radio,diametro;
    cout<<"Introduce radio: "<<endl;
    cin>>radio;
    cout<<"Introduce diametro: "<<endl;
    cin>>diametro;
    try{
      validar(radio,diametro);
    }catch(error e){
        switch(e){
          case datos_no_validos: cout<<"Datos invalidos!!!"<<endl;break;
          default: cout<<"No especificada"<<endl;break;
        }
    }


    circulo.setRadio(radio);
    circulo.setDiametro(diametro);

    cout<<"diametro: "<<circulo.calc_diametro()<<" , area: "<<circulo.calc_area()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Espero te sirva de algo. Gracias por corregir mi respuesta.

Comment: el modificador `throw` es, aparte de innecesario, una mala práctica y algo obsoleto en los nuevos estándares. Por otro lado... ¿en qué momento exacto se lanza una excepción en el código?

Comment: Dentro del metodo validar podría poner una condición para lanzar la excepción. Un dato que no sea válido, un null, etc.

Comment: ¿Coincides conmigo en que es un ejemplo de excepciones... que no lanza excepciones? Si es así, por favor, arregla ese punto y quita el modificador `throw`.

Comment: Sí, así es. Estas en lo correcto.  Solo lo puse de ejemplo.

Comment: Tienes que intentar que los ejemplos solucionen el problema planteado en la pregunta... no vale poner un ejemplo que no tiene nada que ver o que está incompleto porque así no vas a prosperar en [es.so]

Comment: Tienes razón. Modificaré mi respuesta. El problema es que no tenía un compilador a la mano para escribir el código.